# Getting ERROR: Undefined procedure in Prolog

Tags: prolog

In swi-prolog, I loaded a file which just has this:

```
% -*- Mode : Prolog -*- 

sunny.
```

In the terminal, if I do

```
?- sunny.
```

It says `true`. But if I do

```
?- fff.
```

I expect it to say `false`, but it instead says

```
ERROR: Undefined procedure: fff/0 (DWIM could not correct goal)
```

This site http://www.doc.gold.ac.uk/~mas02gw/prolog_tutorial/prologpages/facts.html when doing the example with `foggy.`, it says output should be `no`, but I get an error.

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: This tutorial must be from the 1970s. Today, Prologs rather produce an error which is much much better in many respects. However, if you really want to get that behavior (and don't forget something in [psychedelic light](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jNlcK4fDxRM)) simply say: `set_prolog_flag(unknown, fail).`

Comment: Prolog has no idea what `fff` is. You could do what @false suggests if you want any unknown predicate to just fail (which, by the way, could lead to you having trouble finding typographical errors in larger programs). Or, you can declare certain predicates you care about as dynamic, like `:- dynamic(fff/0).`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are telling prolog to execute a command that does not exist.
If you were to have a file with only:

```
weather(sunny).
```

then running the command

```
weather(foggy).
```

would return false.